# highlighting text with ipyvuetify

Tags: python, voila, ipyvuetify

I have to highligh texts using ipyvuetify being rendered with voila in a jupyter notebook.

In order to achieve that I start as follows:

```
import ipyvuetify as vue
pp=vue.Html(tag='mark',style_='font-weight: bold', children=['this is the first text highlighted green'], background_color='green')
pp2=vue.Html(tag='mark',style_='font-weight: bold', children=['this is a second text highlighted red'], background_color='red')
pp3=vue.Html(tag='p',style_='font-weight: bold', children=['blueblue'], background_color='blue')
display(pp,pp2,pp3)
```

this produces:
[image]

But the desire result should be:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ipyvuetify.Html does not an attribute 'background_color', nor 'color'.
You can set the background-color via the 'style_' tag, just like you did for the bolding.

```
import ipyvuetify as vue
pp=vue.Html(tag='mark',style_='font-weight: bold; background-color:green', children=['this is the first text highlighted green'])
pp2=vue.Html(tag='mark',style_='font-weight: bold; background-color:red', children=['this is a second text highlighted red'])
pp3=vue.Html(tag='p',style_='font-weight: bold; background-color:blue', children=['blueblue'])
display(pp,pp2,pp3)
```